# Docusign API - Locked Fields

Tags: docusignapi, docusigncompositetmplts

I'm using the Docusign API to create an InlineTemplate, but can only have the first signer fill out any fields.

All the fields need to be locked for the remainder of the Signers.  Is there an easy way to accomplish this?

I've tried setting the signer.templateLocked field to true on the additional Signers, but they can still edit the fields.

Setting the locked attribute on the TextTab will lock everyone out of that element, so I'm at a loss of how to accomplish this.

I tried adding the same field to all signers, not only in the signer.tab section, but assigning the recipient id to these elements, but this is giving me 3 fields layering on top of each other for all signers.

I think this should be a common thing, but feel I'm just missing something.

Here is the corresponding json:

```
{
"emailSubject": " ",
"status": "sent",
"enableWetSign": "true",
"compositeTemplates": [{
        "inlineTemplates": [{
                "recipients": {
                    "editors": [],
                    "agents": [],
                    "signers": [{
                            "tabs": {
                                "companyTabs": [],
                                "titleTabs": [],
                                "checkboxTabs": [],
                                "textTabs": [{
                                        "width": "136",
                                        "tabLabel": "OWNER_CONTRACT_NUMBER",
                                        "name": "Policy Number",
                                        "pageNumber": "1",
                                        "documentId": "1",
                                        "yPosition": "139",
                                        "xPosition": "439",
                                        "shared": "true",
                                        "required": "true",
                                        "recipientID": "2"
                                    }, {
                                        "width": "149",
                                        "tabLabel": "OWNER_LAST_NAME",
                                        "name": "Please enter your legal last name.",
                                        "pageNumber": "1",
                                        "documentId": "1",
                                        "yPosition": "139",
                                        "xPosition": "212",
                                        "shared": "true",
                                        "required": "true",
                                        "recipientID": "2"
                                    }
                                ],
                                "emailTabs": [],
                                "fullNameTabs": [],
                                "initialHereTabs": [],
                                "signHereTabs": [{
                                        "name": "Owner's Signature",
                                        "pageNumber": "2",
                                        "documentId": "1",
                                        "yPosition": "347",
                                        "xPosition": "90",
                                        "recipientID": "2"
                                    }
                                ],
                                "SignerAttachmentTabs": [],
                                "dateSignedTabs": [],
                                "radioGroupTabs": []
                            },
                            "routingOrder": "2",
                            "recipientId": "2",
                            "name": "Signer 1",
                            "email": "signer1@test.com",
                            "signerName": "SERVICE_REQ_OWNER"
                        }, {
                            "tabs": {
                                "companyTabs": [],
                                "titleTabs": [],
                                "checkboxTabs": [],
                                "textTabs": [],
                                "emailTabs": [],
                                "fullNameTabs": [],
                                "initialHereTabs": [],
                                "signHereTabs": [],
                                "SignerAttachmentTabs": [],
                                "dateSignedTabs": [],
                                "radioGroupTabs": []
                            },
                            "routingOrder": "1",
                            "clientUserId": "internal-id",
                            "recipientId": "1",
                            "name": "Internal Agent",
                            "email": "noreply@test.com",
                            "signerName": "INTERNAL SIGNER"
                        }
                    ],
                    "certifiedDeliveries": [],
                    "carbonCopies": []
                },
                "sequence": "1"
            }
        ],
        "document": {
            "name": "test document (DOCUSIGN)",
            "documentId": "1"
        }
    }
],
"emailSettings": {
    "replyEmailAddressOverride": "no-reply@test.com",
    "replyEmailNameOverride": "Do Not Reply"
}
```

}

Thanks for helping,
-Jeff

Comment: Is there a reason why you don't create a single instance of the text tab and assign it to the first recipient? The first signer will be able to enter the value, then it will be 'burned-in' and as long as Markup is disabled other signers will be able to view it but not be able to alter it.

Comment: Thanks for the information.  I left out the first requirement that the Internal Signer must have all fields optional.  They will enter in what they know, then send to the first signer which a lot of the fields will become required.  They are the only ones that can edit any fields.  Then any signer after them will be locked.  You're method worked perfectly for the last signer to only view the fields, but do you know a way I can share the same fields between Signer 1 and 2 with Signer > 2 locked?

Answer (score 0):

The only way to do what you are asking is to duplicate all fields and make them optional for the internal signer and conditional for the external signer. You basically going to have the condition be - did the the matching internal field get filled. If it did - you don't show the conditional tab. 
More information on conditional tags:
https://support.docusign.com/en/guides/ndse-user-guide-conditional-fields